# WPF: application shutdown after closing a window

Tags: wpf

I am new to `WPF`. I have two windows that are opening in `app.xaml.cs`.

In `app.xaml.cs` I open `w1` and after some operations `w1` will close. Then `w2` automatically open. As below:

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        w1 a = new w2();
        a.ShowDialog();
        a = null;

        w2 b = new w2();
        b.ShowDialog();
        b = null;
    }
}
```

After `a` closed, b is not showing and application is shutting down.

In `c#` this codes are working in `program.cs`. What is deference and what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this:

[Application.ShutdownMode Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.shutdownmode.aspx)

In your case i guess you should be using `OnExplicitShutdown` and then call [Application.Shutdown Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms597013(v=vs.110).aspx) after your second window closes.

Comment: Application.Current.ShutdownMode = System.Windows.ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown;

Thanx

Answer (score 1):

you can add an event to your first window that will open the second window once it's closed, something similar to this:

```
    public partial class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            w1 a = new w2();
            a.Closed += a_Closed;
            a.ShowDialog();
            a = null;
        }
    }
```

then under the closed event of the first window create the second window:

```
    private void a_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        w2 b = new w2();
        b.ShowDialog();
        b = null; ;
    }
```

Comment: This works but Timothy Ghanem's solution looks more standard. Thanks for your answer.